# dsPIC hangs with extended kalman filter with simulink code generator

Tags: simulink

In the fusion of two ACS712 and INA219 current sensors, the code generated by Simulink generates a block in the dsPIC33EP512GM706 microcontroller.

I am trying to make a control to keep the current constant in a hydrogen generator. The system works perfectly well. But I want to add now the sensory fusion through the extended kalman filter, it works for a while and the micro ends up hanging. Without the sensory fusion block, everything works very well.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: My question is if someone can help me solve the problem, if you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: I have noticed that if I add bias to the sensors, the dsPIC hangs up as soon as the timer that sets the sampling frequency starts to work. The sampling time is 5 ms. And the complete system takes you to the 500 us microcontroller. That is to say that the entire calculation of Kalman is solved in the sampling time, I discard that.

Comment: In the simulation it works well, and in the microcontroller, it works for a moment, but ends up hanging the uC. In the simulation it works well, and in the microcontroller, it works for a moment, but ends up hanging the uC. I have reviewed the compilation options in XC16 v 1.41 of Microchip, I have changed the optimizations and increased the stack, but that is not and should not be the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without the sensory fusion block ...' ? Do you connect A, or D, directly to I_EKF ?

Comment: Did you have implemented the kalman filter in your firmware?

Comment: you want to generate a kalman filter C code ?